# Aspera Client availability for download

Tags: broadcast, aspera

A customer asked me if it was possible to use Aspera FTP instead normal FTP protocol to upload files to their machines.

Obviously I got their address, credentials and so on. The fun part started when I tried to download the Aspera client in order to upload the files to their servers.

It seems that the clients are on the aspera website, but if you want to download the file you have to provide the username and password.

Is this a misconfigured HTTP server or you have to pay even for the client in some ways? Tome sound weird because normally you pay if you want to implement the infrastructure not if you just want to connect to the remote server but who knows..

Answer (score 1):

You probably want Aspera Connect, not the client, which you should be able to [download](http://downloads.asperasoft.com/en/downloads/8?list) without a password. Additionally, your customer should be able to supply you with the Connect installer that matches their server.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the IBM Aspera Desktop Client, a transfer client similar to "filezilla" for FTP, used to be licensed, and is now free of charge, the password protection has been removed.

The IBM Aspera Connect client is also free but requires to use a web interface first on server side.